# Wrong typescript version used in my project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an angular v8 project.

I have in my project typescript v3.4.5

I have also a global version 4.7

When I compile my project I have the error:

Assert identifer is declared twice.

Detail: 'assert' was also declared here and it shows me the typescript v4.7

I don't want my project refers to typescript global version but only the local in my node module project.

I use yarn and my tsconfig is below:

```
            {
          "compilerOptions": {
            "declaration": false,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
            "mapRoot": "./",
            "module": "esnext",
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "target": "es5",
            "typeRoots": [
              "../node_modules/@types"
            ],
            "baseUrl": ".",
            "paths": {
              "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/*" ],
              "@app/*": [ "./app/*" ],
              "@account/*": [ "./account/*" ],
              "@shared/*": [ "./shared/*" ],
              "@node_modules/*": [ "../node_modules/*" ],
              "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ],
              "@metronic/*": [ "./assets/metronic/*" ]
            }
          },
          "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
        }
```